# why inorder traversal is not working in 100.Same tree question in leetcode?

Tags: tree, binary-tree

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> plist = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Integer> qlist = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        inorder(p , plist);
        inorder(q , qlist);
        if(plist.equals(qlist) && plist.size() == qlist.size()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    
    }

    public void inorder(TreeNode root , List<Integer> lst){
        if(root == null){
            return;
        }
        inorder(root.left , lst);
        lst.add(root.val);
        inorder(root.right , lst);
    }
}
```

This is my code for the question. I used Inorder Traversal to solve this question. But my code is failing at this specific 58th testcase in Leetcode which is

Wrong Answer

58 / 60 testcases passed
Input
p =
[1,1]
q =
[1,null,1]

Use Testcase

Output
true

Expected
false

I thought using any of tree traversal techniques will work for this problem. Is my intuition wrong?

Someone please explain this. Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

The Intuition IS wrong

Both

```
   2
  / \
 1   3
```

and

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
```

Have the same inorder traversal.

Inorder Traversal does not provide a unique tree but
two traversals together such as Inorder and Preorder will correspond to a unique tree, so you can also calculate them and compare.

Answer (score 0):

An inorder traversal does not uniquely define the tree's shape.

With two changes you can make your code to work:

- Use a preorder or postorder traversal
- Include all the `null` references in the traversal too, encoded with some specific out-of-range value, like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Then it will work.

As a side note, the following is an antipattern:

```java
if (<bool expression>) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Instead return the boolean expression directly:

```java
return <bool expression>;
```

Also, as `&&` is a shortcircuit operator, you can better *first* compare the size of the lists and only then (when they are equal) start the traversal.

Here is the code when you take those points into account:

```java
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> plist = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Integer> qlist = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        preorder(p, plist);
        preorder(q, qlist);
        return plist.size() == qlist.size() && plist.equals(qlist);
    }

    public void preorder(TreeNode root , List<Integer> lst){
        if (root == null) {
            lst.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // Include an entry for each null reference
            return;
        }
        lst.add(root.val); // pre-order
        preorder(root.left, lst);
        preorder(root.right, lst);
    }
}
```

The next challenge is to solve this problem without storing *all* nodes in lists.

Hint:

> Perform the traversal of *both* trees in "tandem"

Spoiler solution:

> `public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
>          return p == q // Both null or same node reference
>              || (p != null && q != null // Neither null
>                  && p.val == q.val
>                  && isSameTree(p.left, q.left) && isSameTree(p.right, q.right)
>                 );
>      }`